# Errors starting Electron on Raspberry pi2

Tags: javascript, electron, raspberry-pi2

When I make my electron app start, the web app is going to open in the right way, but the serial comunication (with PSoC) that is supposed to work, because on my window's pc is working, on the raspberry is not. The terminal gives me this errors:

```
[2686:1008/103402.722499:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
number_recived
[2686:1008/103409.280279:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[2686:1008/103412.370012:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[2817:1008/103412.501699:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is 
[2744:1008/103412.641274:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[2745:1008/103412.645239:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

So how can I solve this errors? and how can I make the serial comunication works also in raspberry?

Comment: Is the RPi2 running a recent OS version? I'd be a little wary of things like GPU support for current Electron on an old RPi.

Comment: I have already upgraded the OS version, I don’t know what to do

Comment: :shrug: Newer RPi would be my first approach. The RPi2 is 6-ish years old; almost as old as Electron. There may be flags available to turn off GPU support, but IMO trying to make current Electron work on old devices would be more trouble than it’s worth—but it may be doable, just haven’t tried it.